# For added security need to check Tcp/Ip header

Tags: c#, security, model-view-controller, tcp

Is it possible to check the Tcp/Ip header from a Request in MVC C# web environment?

Or through web API?

Comment: What headers would you like to access?

Comment: This question makes no sense whatsoever. Is this a requirement passed on from management, something like _"I heard inspecting TCP/IP headers is good for security, go implement it"_? Can you share your research, and explain what information exactly you're looking for, in what specific header field you think this information resides and how that information will help enhance security?

Comment: Also spoofing a HTTP header is incredibly simple to do.

Comment: @CodeCaster I had the same idea once for bot detection. Try to detect the client OS through TCP specific state and if the OS does not match the user agent that's a spam signal.

Comment: that's normally a firewalls job @usr

Comment: @usr why such a long way around when there's an [Evil bit](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3514)?

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm going to add this useful bit to my bot detection!!1 ;-)

Comment: @usr need to monitor/track ip's TTL as a measure for protecting against man in the middle abuse.

Comment: @usr long ago i tried to detect client's OS by monitoring the tcp/ip flag patterns and status. Even created a long comprehensive table of these against O/S. The problem was that there is a lot of over lap. One can only very broadly group the O/Ss. Even different versions can behave differently. Going by memory these were :Windows, Unix and Sun's  Solaris. It gives a level of confidence/auditing against the reported/expected O/S.

Answer (score 0):

No.

From the Request, you won't see the TCP packet headers. The HttpWebRequest object represents a potentially multi-packet (mega-packet, in fact) transaction. You could have millions of packet headers to inspect on a large upload, for example.

You might get somewhere wiring in a custom Windows Filtering Platform (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366510(v=vs.85).aspx) interceptor and coordinating with that, if you need that level of packet review.

Or perhaps the datagrams aren't the thing that you really mean to inspect?

Comment: tcp/ip network transactions are open to "man in the middle" attack/abuse. The only way i know one can  mitgate this is through careful monitoring usage of  ip headers. Even this can fail but it gives, at least, one level of protection.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I knew of it. But got to check it some time later.